# how to create a floating reload button

Tags: css

I have following layout in a html page:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|                          | Reload   |
| dynamic graph image div  +----------+
|                                     |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Dynamic graph image div will fetch a graph from another php page by jquery POST method and there will be a reload button (Reload) which should be over dynamic div. This dynamic graph will be changed upon each query. After pressing this Reload link, image/graph of this dynamic div will be fetched again by jquery code. By this way, the user does not need to reload the whole page.

But how can I place Reload link so that it will on top of the image/graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS issue not a jquery issue.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="image.png"/>
    <a class="reload" href="#">Reload</a>
</div>


.container 
{
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
}

.image
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;

}

.reload
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
    display:block;
    width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS:

```
.container_div {
    position:relative;
}
.container_content{
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}
.floating_button{
    position:absoltue;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

with some sample html:

```
<div class="contianer_div">
    <div class="container_content">
        Your content here
    </div>
    <div class="floating_button">
        button content
    </div>
</div>
```

that should do the trick;

Further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="dynamic">
    <a id="button">reload</a>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#dynamic{
   position: relative;
}

#button{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```